# Creating a 'New User' Pop-up using tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I am trying to make an application where upon clicking a link you get to open a pop-up where you can create a new user for the application. This asks for user ID, password and confirm password. When password and confirm password don't match, it gives a messagebox saying passwords don't match, but it again gives the same message when the passwords are actually matching. Can someone please help with resolving this?

```
def new_user_function(*args):
    if password == confirm_pass:
        MyDB.add_new_user(email, password)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Passwords don't match")

def new_user_function_popup(*args):
    """This will open a pop up window for adding new users"""
    user_popup = Toplevel()
    user_popup.title("Create New user")

    ttk.Label(user_popup, text = "Enter Email ID").grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = E)
    ttk.Label(user_popup, text = "New Password").grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = E)
    ttk.Label(user_popup, text = "Confirm Password").grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = E)

    ttk.Entry(user_popup, width = 25, textvariable = user_id).grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = (E,W))
    ttk.Entry(user_popup, width = 25, textvariable = password, show = "*").grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = (E,W))
    ttk.Entry(user_popup, width = 25, textvariable = confirm_pass, show = "*").grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = (E,W))

    ttk.Button(user_popup, text = 'Create', command = new_user_function).grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = (E,W))  

user_id = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
confirm_pass = StringVar()
upload_fp = StringVar()
save_fp = StringVar()
```

Comment: Change to `if password.get() == confirm_pass.get():`.

Comment: Thanks. It made it work!

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by [stovfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7414759/stovfl), the solution to this is using the `get()` function. `StringVar()` is a class that makes a python object, but to get the values, we need to use the method defined by in the class, and `get()` does that.